# What's the value of setting a DataContext on a ListBox when you can just give it an ItemsSource?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm still really new to data binding in WPF, so I'm not sure what the purpose of a data context is supposed to be when you can just fill in the list by setting the ItemsSource property whenever you want it to change.

Comment: Because the ListBox may need a different DataContext than the parent it belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth noting that `DataContext` isn't a property of `ListBox`, but of a lower-level class it inherits, namely [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.FrameworkElement.aspx).  In other words, almost every type of visual element you use in XAML will have a DataContext -- it's a function of WPF's class hierarchy.  You're right, though, that DataContext is typically used on panels and other elements that contain direct content.  It's not so useful for controls that do not contain any direct content (ListBox contains children, but their data contexts are set separately by the control, so they do not inherit ListBox's context directly).

Also note that setting `ItemsSource` sets a single value, while setting `DataContext` establishes a new reference point for any other bindings on the object and its visual-tree children.  There could be scenarios where `ItemsSource` doesn't participate in binding, and instead is set by a static resource:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <viewmodel:StringCollection x:Key="items">
            <clr:String>Foo</clr:String>
            <clr:String>Bar</clr:String>
        </viewmodel:StringCollection>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource items}" 
        DataContext="{Binding MetaData}" 
        ToolTip="{Binding}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the ListBox may need a different DataContext than the parent it belongs to

Example:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}">
    <-- MainViewModel.Something
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Something}" />   
    <-- MainViewModel.ViewModel1.Items
    <ListBox DataContext="{Binding ViewModel1}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" /> 
    <-- MainViewModel.Items
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

DataContext, as the name suggests, simply defines the context of data for the particular framework element (Listbox in the given case). While binding any property on the control to the data, if not explicitly defined, searches for the source within DataContext. So, if you bind the ItemsSource property and not explicitly define the Path, it will search for the binding source of ItemsSource prperty within the DataContext of the listbox.

Hence, we need DataContext also in this case to change the Data source depending on the requirement in order to get Data for the binding for whole control.